# Android ListView SetSelector Issue

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView being created in code like this:

```
ListView lv  = new ListView(this); 
lv.setId(GENERALLISTVIEWID);
lv.setBackgroundColor(0x333333); 
lv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
lv.setDivider(null);
lv.setDividerHeight(0);
lv.setSelector(R.drawable.mainselector);
```

And in my **mainselector**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <item android:drawable="@color/orange" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_selected="true"/>
</selector>
```

The problem is, when I select the row, the entire listview underneath the cells lights up orange.  Why is not just the single row turning orange?

Comment: Do you want selected Oagnge and others background white?

Answer (score 2):

Okay I have solved the issue, I was making the mistake of applying the resource to my entire ListView instead of to my ListView row.

Now it is quite obvious.  I have applied mainselector as the background to my ListView cell.xml instead.